# How to get all posts of every user with MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api

So. I have built a simple social media app.

Here is my Post model

```
    const PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    userId: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
    },
    desc: {
      type: String,
      max: 500,
    },
    img: {
      type: String,
    },
    likes: {
      type: Array,
      default: [],
    },
  },
  { timestamps: true }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model("Post", PostSchema);
```

I want to retrieve every posts **of every user that exists**.
So, in my postController, I tried to write the following API:

```
const getAllPosts = async (req,res,next)=>{
    try {
      const posts = await Post.find();
      res.status(200).json(posts);
    } catch (err) {
      next(err);
      
    }
  }
```

Here is the middleware

```
//get all posts
router.get("/allposts",verifyAdmin, getAllPosts);
```

But it gives me 500 internal error.

I am new to JS, so can anyone help me?

EDIT: This is the error at server side (Postman screenshot)
[image]

Comment: It might be helpful to tell us what the actual error on the server side is.

Comment: please check if this is what you want?

Answer (score 1):

the problem is the `find()`, this function has required params (first: an object with filter). In this case, you can use `.find({})`.

The official documentation: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model-find

Comment: I added {} inside `.find()`, still the error persists and btw do we have to add userId inside find()? If yes, this means I can only get a particular user's posts.

My question here is, is there anyway I can get "EVERY" users posts?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, could you try with use `ObjectId type` instead of `String` in the schema (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#objectids)?

Answer (score 0):

Somehow it responded to me with 200 server status when I changed its endpoint from

```
//get all posts
router.get("/allposts",verifyAdmin, getAllPosts);
```

to

```
 //get all posts
router.get("/",verifyAdmin, getAllPosts);
```

Would be thankful if anyone can tell me what can be the reason behind this?

Comment: Do you also have any other get routes e.g. "/api/posts/:id" if so then you need to keep in mind that the order of the routes matters

Comment: Yes I have, can you tell me more about the order of routes?

Comment: Here is a good example:
https://gabrieleromanato.name/order-of-routes-when-using-parameters-in-expressjs